# How to reshape tensor of pooling boxes back to input tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a tensor:

```
 x = ([[[[ -633.,   377.,  -691.,  -683.,    50.,   936.],
         [ -121.,   851.,  -593.,  -943.,   891.,   410.],
         [ -776.,  -560.,  -270.,   816.,   425.,  -629.],
         [ -172.,   599.,  -549.,  -520.,  -684.,   -57.],
         [  265.,  -323.,   726.,   -98.,   780.,   109.],
         [   22., -1017.,    22.,   248.,  -617.,   449.]]]])
```

of shape `(1, 1, 6, 6)`. I tried to split it into pooling boxes of size 2 and back it to source tensor.
When I coded

```
stride = 2
c = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] // stride, stride, x.shape[3] // stride, stride).swapaxes(3, 4).reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], -1, stride * stride)
```

I got what I wanted - tensor where every last dimension vector is pooling box of shape (2, 2):

```
[[[[ -633.   377.  -121.   851.]
   [ -691.  -683.  -593.  -943.]
   [   50.   936.   891.   410.]
   [ -776.  -560.  -172.   599.]
   [ -270.   816.  -549.  -520.]
   [  425.  -629.  -684.   -57.]
   [  265.  -323.    22. -1017.]
   [  726.   -98.    22.   248.]
   [  780.   109.  -617.   449.]]]]
```

But when I tried to back it to x `d = c.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] // stride, stride, x.shape[3] // stride, stride).swapaxes(3, 4).reshape(x.shape)`, I got this tensor:

```
[[[[ -633.   377.  -121.   851.]
   [ -691.  -683.  -593.  -943.]
   [   50.   936.   891.   410.]
   [ -776.  -560.  -172.   599.]
   [ -270.   816.  -549.  -520.]
   [  425.  -629.  -684.   -57.]
   [  265.  -323.    22. -1017.]
   [  726.   -98.    22.   248.]
   [  780.   109.  -617.   449.]]]]
```

How can I get input tensor by changing tensor `c` of pooling boxes?